# FLUTTER : POD INSTALL ERROR ON MY ANDROID TERMINAL BUT I AM ABLE TO RUN IT FROM MAC M1 TERMINAL

Tags: iphone, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Comment: Have you tried running the command `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and then re-running the command? The error indicates that your terminal is in ascii mode, while you need to be in UTF-8 mode to have it work properly.

Comment: Yes. I tried everything from adding this to my ~./profile and also updating my cocoapods. I have been facing new errors after update and also getting this error.